# Ubuntu 15.10: Error thrown on Magento Admin and Homepage

Tags: magento-2.1

I have installed a fresh setup of Magento 2.1 on my Ubuntu 15.10 and everything worked out perfectly. But as soon as I enabled my module which I currently developed on my Windows machine, I received following error

```
There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 963627958
```

After I disabled my module it still showed the same error, but the error was gone as soon as I ran following command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

I enabled my module again and ran above code again and worked out fine.
This time I cleared **Static Cache** and **Javascript/CSS cache** from **Admin Panel**, I encountered the same error again and this time above code didn't help at all.

Before coding in Windows, I was on Ubuntu and because of this same issue encountered again and again I switched to Windows, but Windows was too slow to develop so I again switched to Ubuntu.

This error is a nightmare, I never encountered this error on Windows.

Please help.

Comment: Open var/report/963627958 and identify the cause or provide the error in question.

Comment: thanks @krishnaijjadaati95Dev I didn't know where to look for errors, in windows the errors were displayed on the same page, so it was easy to figure out what was the issue, is there anyway to get the error on page, i mean i dont have to go and look for it in the `var/report/` folder